# Mathematical formula required

Tags: math

An input sequence is given. Each stage of the iteration finds another sequence by calculating difference between n-i and n-i-1 number. We continue the process and at the end of the last iteration (iteration: n-1) we find only 1 number. What is the mathematical formulation for finding the last number as shown in the image?
[image: Method of Common Differences]

Comment: SHow what you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please check the [FAQ - How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. Especially, it is unclear what output you get from your code versus what output you expected. Ideally provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so that others can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Andreas What makes you think the output he got is not the output he expected?

Comment: An input sequence of N number is given. I find the differences between two consecutive numbers in each iteration. Basically what I want is the output at N-1 th iteration, which is going to be only 1 number. I want the mathematical formula to find that last number. ( It will check whether the number is 0 or not and decide further actions )

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the mathematical formulation is finding the `n-1`'th derivative of the degree-`n-1` polynomial passing through all points `(i,arr[i])`. That derivative is guaranteed to be a constant. This is equivalent to the coefficient of the term with exponent `n-1`, divided by `(n-1)!`.

This method is a special case of what is known as [Neville's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville%27s_algorithm).